# Jira Quick-filter to show all task with subtasks assigned to current user

Tags: jira, jql

Currently, I have a quick filter to show me my task that does this:

```
assignee = currentUser()
```

This works ok, but doesn't show me tasks that are assigned to someone else, but have subtasks assigned to me. Is it possible to make it show me both tasks assigned to me, and tasks that have subtasks assigned to me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a filter for all of your subtask from the following JQL:

```
issuetype in subtaskIssueTypes() and assignee = currentUser()
```

Then, using [Craftforge JQL Functions Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.craftforge.jira.craftforge-jql-functions-plugin), use the following JQL to find their parents:

```
issue in parentIssuesFromFilter("filter name or its id")
```

Answer (score 2):

The following query will return **all parent tasks**, which have sub-tasks assigned to the current user. (The parent task need not be assigned to current user)

```
issueFunction in parentsOf("assignee = currentUser() ")
```

Note: `issueFunction` requires the ScriptRunner plugin and it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Kuf's answer, it's sometimes much simpler to write the whole thing in one query especially with Swimlanes or Quick-Filters in Greenhopper, rather than creating and saving custom filter.

For instance, to show Un-finished Issues or Sub-tasks in one quick-filter on Greenhopper:

```
status!=Closed or issue in parentIssuesFromQuery("issuetype in subtaskIssueTypes() AND status!=Closed ")
```

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to Issues (in header) > Search for issues, then enter your search criteria.