# How to filter out jira tickets based on the assignee of subtasks?

Tags: jira, jql

I have quite a number of JIRA tickets, each of them have some label attached to them. Each ticket have few sub-tasks that are assigned to different users.

I want to filter the Jira based on following criteria:

1. Label
2. Assignee of one of the subtask

Is it possible to do so?

Here is the query that I need to complete:

labels in (sprint-package-1, sprint-package-2, sprint-package-3, sprint-package-4 ) and status not in (Abandoned)

What I am trying to achieve (in simple words) :

Show me only those JIRAs that have label = 'xyz' and their status is not abandoned and they have a sub-task assigned to 'somerandomuser'

**UPDATE**

I know that a similar question exists ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649036/jira-quick-filter-to-show-all-task-with-subtasks-assigned-to-current-user?rq=1)) but the solution requires one to have a plugin [Craftforge JQL Functions Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.craftforge.jira.craftforge-jql-functions-plugin/server/overview). I cannot use any plugin.